# SQL Server - how to convert row into column in sql server depending on sequence field dynamically?

Tags: sql-server

I'm new to SQL Server and I've tried to read about [Pivot and Unpivot](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx), but I don't really know if `Pivot and Unpivot` can help me out.

I have a sample SQL dataset like this :

```
seqID | name | SL_Name |
------+------+---------+
  1   | act  | null    |
 1/1  | pas  | null    |
1/1/1 | qux  | foo     |
1/1/2 | qux2 | foo2    |
-and--|--so--|---on----|
 1/2  | bar2 | null    |
1/2/1 | qux2 | bar     |
-and--|--so--|---on----|
  2   | foo2 | null    |
 2/1  | bar2 | null    |
2/1/1 | qux2 | bar     |
-and--|--so--|---on----|
```

Expected new table looks like :

```
seqid_n | seqid_n_n | seqid_n_n_n | seqid_n_(...)|
--------+-----------+-------------+--------------+
act     | pas       | qux         |      and     |
act     | pas       | qux2        |      so      |
act     | bar2      | qux2        |      on      |
foo2    | bar2      | qux2        |              |
```

Expected table getting depend on seqID_n, if seqID value = `1`, it must store at 1st field, and if seqID value = `2/1` it must store at 2nd field, with 1st field value is seqID value = `2`, and so on

Can anyone help me out?

EDITED

showing full dataset:

[image: dataset]

> DownVoter, please let me know if my question is not clearly enough

Comment: any idea please>

Comment: Can you get seqID with numbers greater than 9 (e.g. can you get `1/10`)? There are a variety of ways you can tackle this, from recursive ctes with a (dynamic) pivot or multiple joins, etc. e.g. You could make something like the following dynamic: `SELECT seqid_n = T1.name, seqid_n_n = T2.name, seqid_n_n_n = T3.name FROM mytable AS T1 JOIN mytable AS T2 ON LEN(T2.seqID) = 3 AND T2.seqID LIKE T1.seqID + '/[1-9]' JOIN mytable AS T3 ON LEN(T3.seqID) = 5 AND T3.seqID LIKE T2.seqID + '/[1-9]' WHERE LEN(T1.seqID) = 1;`

Comment: Can there be any number of seqid or is it fixed? To use `PIVOT` you need to explicitly state the columns beforehand. So if you don't know that you can't use it. The advice as always is: do it in the reporting tool

Comment: @flix, remove values with `and, so, on`. Show complete expected result for given sample data. It's not clear for me how are you gettig 3 rows for `act` and only 1 for `foo2`. And what's the maximal depth?

Comment: @ZLK the seqID 'maybe' would be greater than 9

Comment: @uzi edited with full dataset as requested, can you help me sir?

Comment: @flix, no need to show full dataset. Your provided sample text data almost enough. Just add third column from image, it might help. I wanted you to show full expected result to make it clear.

Comment: @uzi @ZLK query is work with my issue above (with seqID `n/n/n`) , but how to make it dynamically? in case if my seqID would be `n/n/n/n/n`, and `n` number can be greater than 9